# Swift Array Objects Invalidated During Delete

Tags: realm, swift3

*Swift 3, Xcode 8, Realm 2.0.0*

I have a Realm object that has a List property called like this:

```
class Entry: Object{
  let approaches = List<Approach>()
  //...
}
```

I pull an `Entry` object that has an `Approach` list in it so that `entry.approaches` is a list of approaches.
I then load up my own separate array with the list so that I can manipulate its contents using `Approach` objects.

```
var approaches = [Approach]()
for approach in entry.approaches{
  approaches.append(approach)
}
```

Prior to saving some edits to the `Entry`, I want to remove all existing `approaches` and replace them with new elements I put in the `approaches` array elsewhere in my code.

```
try realm.write {
  print(approaches) //This prints out my Approach objects
  realm.delete(entry.approaches) //Clear out existing items in list
  print(approaches) //-!- This prints [[invalid object], [invalid object]]
}
```

If I manually put the Realm objects in my own `approaches`array, why are they invalidated when `entry.approaches` is deleted?

Is there a better way to replace all objects in a list than this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's intended behavior. Maybe you are confusing deleting objects from Realm and removing objects from List. `realm.delete()` execute the former. The objects were deleted from Realm. Then all references pointed to the objects would be invalidated.
If you'd like to clear `entry.approaches`, not deleting from Realm, you can use `List.removeAll()` method.

```
try realm.write {
    entry.approaches.removeAll()
}
```

FYI: Copying all list items to array can be written like the following. No need to iterate list.

```
let approaches = [Approach](entry.approaches)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. That tip about populating the array is particularly nice.